# How do I create and test dialog for a custom alexa skill?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, alexa-skills-kit

I am developing an Alexa skill with account linking on an ROR API. I have the LaunchRequest working but when I try to make an IntentRequest (which has 3 slots) I am not getting a dialogState and Alexa is just telling me there is a problem with my response. I built the skill model with Amazon's skill builder beta. Since dialogs are not testable in the console or simulator, it's almost impossible to figure what's up. Here is the model:

```
{
"intents": [
{
  "name": "AMAZON.CancelIntent",
  "samples": []
},
{
  "name": "AMAZON.HelpIntent",
  "samples": []
},
{
  "name": "AMAZON.StopIntent",
  "samples": []
},
{
  "name": "RateWineIntent",
  "samples": [...]
   ,
  "slots": [
    {
      "name": "wine",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
      "samples": [
        "{wine}",
        "wine {wine}",
        "wine number {wine}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "rating",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
      "samples": [
        "{rating}",
        "a rating of {rating}",
        "rate it a {rating}",
        "give it a rating of {rating}"
      ]
    },
    {
      "name": "taster",
      "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
      "samples": [
        "{taster}",
        "taster number {taster}",
        "taster {taster}",
        "for taster {taster}",
        "for taster number {taster}"
      ]
    }
  ]
}],
"prompts": [
{
  "id": "Confirm.Intent-RateWineIntent",
  "promptVersion": "1.0",
  "definitionVersion": "1.0",
  "variations": [
    {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "value": "I have a rating of {rating} on wine {wine} for taster {taster}. Is that correct."
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "Elicit.Intent-RateWineIntent.IntentSlot-wine",
  "promptVersion": "1.0",
  "definitionVersion": "1.0",
  "variations": [
    {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "value": "OK, which wine number?"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "Elicit.Intent-RateWineIntent.IntentSlot-rating",
  "promptVersion": "1.0",
  "definitionVersion": "1.0",
  "variations": [
    {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "value": "And what rating for this wine?"
    }
  ]
},
{
  "id": "Elicit.Intent-RateWineIntent.IntentSlot-taster",
  "promptVersion": "1.0",
  "definitionVersion": "1.0",
  "variations": [
    {
      "type": "PlainText",
      "value": "Great. And for which taster number?"
    }
  ]
}
],
"dialog": {
"version": "1.0",
"intents": [
  {
    "name": "RateWineIntent",
    "confirmationRequired": true,
    "prompts": {
      "confirm": "Confirm.Intent-RateWineIntent"
    },
    "slots": [
      {
        "name": "wine",
        "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
        "elicitationRequired": true,
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {
          "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-RateWineIntent.IntentSlot-wine"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "rating",
        "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
        "elicitationRequired": true,
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {
          "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-RateWineIntent.IntentSlot-rating"
        }
      },
      {
        "name": "taster",
        "type": "AMAZON.NUMBER",
        "elicitationRequired": true,
        "confirmationRequired": false,
        "prompts": {
          "elicit": "Elicit.Intent-RateWineIntent.IntentSlot-taster"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
]
}
}
```

and here is the response:

```
{
 "session": {
"sessionId": "MY-SESSION-ID",
"application": {
  "applicationId": "MY-APPLICATION-ID"
},
"attributes": {},
"user": {
  "userId": "MY-USER-ID"
},
"new": true
},
"request": {
"type": "IntentRequest",
"requestId": "REQUEST-ID",
"locale": "en-US",
"timestamp": "2017-05-18T06:41:56Z",
"intent": {
  "name": "RateWineIntent",
  "slots": {
    "taster": {
      "name": "taster"
    },
    "rating": {
      "name": "rating"
    },
    "wine": {
      "name": "wine"
    }
  }
}
},
"version": "1.0"
}
```

I can fill slots, but it will not produce a dialogState. Any ideas? Anybody figure out a better way to test this without screaming at your Dot?

Comment: Screaming at echosim.io?

Comment: Just kidding. I was excited when the introduced the dialogue and optional slots. I had developed my own finite-state-machine for this sort of stuff myself and I found out that I'm still preferring my own implementation because, among other things, I can test it properly using unittest. If you are interested: https://github.com/josepvalls/ask.py

Comment: Thanks @Josep, but I'm using ROR for the back end. I eventually figured it out. I was not returning the full response JSON. I thought, based on the docs, that in dialog the response was abbreviated. It actually works really well now and saves a lot of time filling slots manually.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was with my response. I was just returning the `<Directive/>` portion of the response based on what I was reading in Amazon's docs. Which, is where the problem is. My suggestion to any programmer who wants to work with Alexa is start [here](https://developer.amazon.com/public/solutions/alexa/alexa-skills-kit/docs/alexa-skills-kit-interface-reference). Learn the request/response JSONs because mistakes here are hard to test. Amazon's docs seem to force you into learning about voice design before programming, which I think is putting the cart before the horse.